# Automatic log file downloader, receiving 404 errors?

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I am trying to code an automatic log downloader for a Nitrado server I am running, because I am out working some days, I want to be able to store all the logs in-case I need to look through them at a later date.

Using the nitrAPI, and with a little help from chatGPT, I created what I hope to be a program that should just pull the files into the existing folder when the program runs, however I am encountering 404 errors when the program tries to log into the file server.

```
import requests

def download_logs(server_id, username, password):
    base_url = f"https://api.nitrado.net/services/{server_id}/gameservers/file_server"
    auth = (username, password)
    # Get the list of available log files
    logs_url = f"{base_url}/games/dayz/log"
    response = requests.get(logs_url, auth=auth)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error retrieving log files: {response.status_code} {response.text}")
        return

    log_files = response.json()
    print(f"Available log files: {', '.join(log_files)}")

    # Download each log file
    for log_file in log_files:
        log_url = f"{logs_url}/{log_file}"
        response = requests.get(log_url, auth=auth)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(log_file, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
                print(f"Downloaded: {log_file}")
        else:
            print(f"Error downloading {log_file}: {response.status_code} {response.text}")
# Set your Nitrado server ID, username, and password
server_id = "SERVER_ID"
username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"

# Call the function to download logs
download_logs(server_id, username, password
```